# Erasure code for files with aribtrary length

Tags: c, encoding, error-correction

I'm searching for an (RS) erasure code in C that can handle more then the usual (255,XXX), preferable arbitrary length. I know that the RS-Codes is not efficient with large files but if I understood the theory behind it correctly, it is possible. Nevertheless, I can only find codes with a maximum of 255 byte maximum output.

Is there a particular reason for it besides the inefficiency?

Comment: Why not split your input into small chunks of 128 bytes and apply an erasure code to each such chunk? That's how it's usually done.

Comment: I know but the algorithm/protocol requires it. :-/ I have another idea how to solve it but I'm still curious if something like this exists.

Comment: If the protocol requires that, doesn't this imply a solution already exists? How can the protocol not support shorter erasure codes?

Comment: It's more a theoretical construction in a crypto paper that requires a erasure code with those attributes. By just using blocks instead of encoding the whole file would weaken the construction.